# Rod cutting variant

Tags: algorithm, optimization, recursion, big-o, brute-force

I have the following **algorithmic problem** :

Given a customer order describing mutliple timber of different lengths with a precision of 2 decimal places.
For example: 2 * 1,50 ; 2 * 0,50  (4 timber needed, 2 pieces of length 1,50 meter and two pieces of length 0,50 meter).

**In stock are an unlimited number of timber, however with the fixed lengths 2, 3, 4 and 5 meters.** 
The timber from the customer order needs to be cut from the beams in stock. A cut itself has 0 thickness as idealization.
**Any beam length > 5,00 meter in the customer order is not possible.**

**Goal is to minimize the waste of timber which is a result after completing the customer order. When there are multiple solutions with minimal waste, the solution with the minimal amount of cuts is the optimal one.**

In the above noted customer order example, one would take two 2,00 meter timber from stock and cut each of them in a 0,5 and 1,5 meter piece.
Therefore the algorithm would produce waste = 0, with 2 cuts.

```
Example 1:
Customer order: 2 * 1,50 ; 2 * 0,50  
Output: 
Total waste: 0  
Total cuts: 2  
2,00 --> 1,50 ; 0,50 waste 0  
2,00 --> 1,50 ; 0,50 waste 0

Example 2:  
Customer order: 2 * 2,48 ; 1 * 2,68 ;  2 * 3,12 ; 1 * 1,32; 2 * 1,33 ; 1 * 1,34  
Output:     
Total waste: 1,80  
Total cuts: 7  
4,00 --> 1,33 ; 1,33 ; 1,34 waste 0  
4,00 --> 2,68 ; 1,32 waste 0  
4,00 --> 3,12 ;      waste 0,88  
4,00 --> 3,12 ;      waste 0,88  
5,00 --> 2,48 ; 2,48 waste 0,04
```

The brute force approach has very poor performance at a given number of beams in the customer order.

Anyone an idea for a good algorithmic approach ? 
Any ideas about the big-o complexity ?

Comment: Sounds similar to the [cutting stock problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem).

Comment: It is similar, but in my problem the timber in the customer order don't have a fixed length. In other words, there could be say 10 beams needed in the customer order, each of them with a different length.

Comment: are only timber of sizes 2,3,4,5 available what if customer demands timber of size 10??

Comment: Any beam length > 5,00 meter in the customer order is not possible.

Comment: also what is the maximum number of total orders ??

Comment: What do you mean with "the maximum number of total orders" ?

Comment: yes total number of orders

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32487/discussion-between-sasha-sami-and-dutchman79)

Comment: For clearity: the number of beams in the customer order are not set to a maximum.

Comment: "there could be say 10 beams needed in the customer order, each of them with a different length" This falls under the cutting stock problem still.

Comment: As I understand it, the difference lies in the fact that in my problem the timber in stock also have different lengths.

Comment: Check [this](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~kksivara/ma505/handouts/gilmore-gomory2.pdf) out, page 864/865 and 886 - it does mention different stock lengths, but I have not examined this further and am not really familiar with this problem.